# Static Indexers?

Tags: c#, .net, static, indexer, static-indexers

Why are static indexers disallowed in C#? I see no reason why they should not be allowed and furthermore they could be very useful.

For example:

```
public static class ConfigurationManager 
{
        public object this[string name]
        {
            get => ConfigurationManager.getProperty(name);
            set => ConfigurationManager.editProperty(name, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This will write the value to the property. Will overwrite if the property is already there
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">Name of the property</param>
        /// <param name="value">Value to be wrote (calls ToString)</param>
        public static void editProperty(string name, object value) 
        {
            var ds = new DataSet();
            var configFile = new FileStream("./config.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            ds.ReadXml(configFile);

            if (ds.Tables["config"] == null)
                ds.Tables.Add("config");

            var config = ds.Tables["config"];

            if (config.Rows[0] == null) 
                config.Rows.Add(config.NewRow());

            if (config.Columns[name] == null) 
                config.Columns.Add(name);

            config.Rows[0][name] = value.ToString();

            ds.WriteXml(configFile);
            configFile.Close();
        }

        public static void addProperty(string name, object value) =>
            ConfigurationManager.editProperty(name, value);

        public static object getProperty(string name) 
        {
            var ds = new DataSet();
            var configFile = new FileStream("./config.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            ds.ReadXml(configFile);
            configFile.Close();

            if (ds.Tables["config"] == null) return null;

            var config = ds.Tables["config"];

            if (config.Rows[0] == null) return null;
            if (config.Columns[name] == null) return null;

            return config.Rows[0][name];
        }
    }
```

The above code would benefit greatly from a static indexer. However it won't compile because static indexers are not allowed. Why is this so?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Indexer notation requires a reference to `this`. Since static methods don't have a reference to any particular instance of the class, you can't use `this` with them, and consequently you can't use indexer notation on static methods.

The solution to your problem is using a singleton pattern as follows:

```
public class Utilities
{
    private static ConfigurationManager _configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager();
    public static ConfigurationManager ConfigurationManager => _configurationManager;
}

public class ConfigurationManager
{
    public object this[string value]
    {
        get => new object();
        set => // set something
    }
}
```

Now you can call `Utilities.ConfigurationManager["someKey"]` using indexer notation.

Comment: But why does the indexer have to use 'this'? It doesn't have to access instance data

Comment: +1 for Malfist's comment. Just because it uses "this" for an instance indexer doesn't mean they couldn't come up with other syntax.

Comment: Agreed. You are begging the question. You've basically said the reason it's not allowed is because it's not allowed. -1 because the question was "why is it not allowed?"

Comment: I doubt indexer notation "requires a reference to `this`". Indexer notation may be using the *token* `this`, but that is hardly related to the `this` expression as it appears in bodies of instance methods.

Comment: -1 because this answer assumes that the current notation is the only possible notation if a static indexer were implemented. The use of `this` in an indexer is not necessarily required, it was likely chosen above other keywords because it made the most sense. For a static implementation, the following syntax may be quite viable: `public object static[string value]`. No need to use the keyword `this` in a static context.

Comment: -1 because the 'this' token is used as a keyword rather than being a reference to the 'this' object. And extension methods are pretty happy at using 'this' as a keyword while being static at the same time.

Comment: @DaveInCaz Because that's not correct. It says "Indexer notation requires a reference to this". 

That's not true, the "this" in the indexer syntax is nothing more than a keyword and does not refer to the reference to the current object in any way; C# itself contradicts the statement: extension methods use "this" as a keyword in parameter declaration.

Nothing (specially not the overloaded use of the "this" keyword) would've prevented to implement static indexers, it was just a deliberate choice. 

See also comments by Jon Skeet & einsteinsci for alternate syntax or O.R.Mapper on "this".

Answer (score 110):

I believe it was considered not to be terribly useful. I think it's a shame too - an example I tend to use is Encoding, where `Encoding.GetEncoding("foo")` could be `Encoding["Foo"]`. I don't think it would come up *very* often, but aside from anything else it just feels a little inconsistent not to be available.

I would have to check, but I *suspect* it's available in IL (Intermediate Language) already.

Comment: Intermediate Language - sort of assembly language for .NET.

Comment: FWIW, changing `instance` to `static` in the IL for a property and getter method on a default property results in ilasm complaining `syntax error at token 'static'`; I'm not great at meddling in the affairs of IL but that sounds like at least an initial no.

Comment: I cant believe how many times I wish I could use a static indexer, both in static classes and non-static ones (mainly singletons as I tend to make Instance a non-public property).

Answer (score 10):

As a work-around, you can define an instance indexer on a singleton/static object (say that ConfigurationManager is a singleton, instead of being a static class):

```
class ConfigurationManager
{
  //private constructor
  ConfigurationManager() {}
  //singleton instance
  public static ConfigurationManager singleton;
  //indexer
  object this[string name] { ... etc ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also in need (well, more like nice-to-have) of an static indexer to store attributes, so I figured out a somewhat awkward workaround:

Within the class you want to have an static indexer (here: Element), create a subclass of the same name + "Dict". Give it a readonly static as instance of said subclass, and then add your desired indexer.

Last, add the class as static import (hence the subclass to only expose the static field).

```
import static Element.ElementDict;

public class Element {
    // .... 
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, object> elemDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public class ElementDict {
        public readonly static ElementDict element = new ElementDict();
        public object this[string key] {
            get => elemDict.TryGetValue(key, out object o) ? o : null;
            set => elemDict[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can use it either capitalized as Type, or without as dictionary:

```
var cnt = element["counter"] as int;
element["counter"] = cnt;
```

But alas, if one were to actually use object as "value"-Type, then the below would be still shorter (at least as declaration), and also provide immediate Typecasting:

```
public static T load<T>(string key) => elemDict.TryGetValue(key, out object o) ? (T) o : default(T);
public static void store<T>(string key, T value) => elemDict[key] = value;

var cnt = Element.load<int>("counter");
Element.store("counter", cnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the newer constructs in C# 6, you might simplify the singleton pattern with a property expression body. 
For instance, I used the following shortcut which works nicely with code-lense:

```
public static class Config
{
   public static NameValueCollection Get => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
}
```

It has the added benefit of being find-replace-able for upgrading older code and unifying your application settings access.

Answer (score -3):

The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class. Static member functions do not have a this pointer. The this keyword can be used to access members from within constructors, instance methods, and instance accessors.(retrieved from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz%28v=vs.71%29.ASPX)).  Since this references an instance of the class it conflicts with the nature of static, since static isn't associated with an instance of the class.

One workaround would be the following which allows you to use the indexer against a private 
Dictionary so you only need to create a new instance and you access the static part.

```
    public class ConfigurationManager 
{
    public ConfigurationManager()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }
    public object this[string keyName]
    {
        get
        {
                return ConfigurationManagerItems[keyName];
        }
        set
        {
                ConfigurationManagerItems[keyName] = value;
        }
    }
    private static Dictionary<string, object> ConfigurationManagerItems = new Dictionary<string, object>();        
}
```

This allows you to skip the whole accessing a member of the class and just create an instance of it and index it.

```
    new ConfigurationManager()["ItemName"]
```

Comment: its an interesting workaround, but 1) it introduces side-effects (creation of an empty instance object) which could lead to memory pressure and fragmentation in some environments, 2) the extra characters wasted by `new ()` could have been used for qualifier name of a singleton instead, like `.Current`

Comment: Just like [Juliet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/401275/1430156), this does not answer the question why static indexers are not supported. First, the question does not restrict the term "static indexer" to "something that uses the `this` keyword", and second, `this` in the syntax `public string this[int index]` is strictly speaking not even a use of a `this` pointer (as it may occur in the body of instance methods), but just another use of the *token* `this`. The syntax `public static string this[int index]` might *look* a bit counterintuitive, but it would still be unambiguous.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It could just as well be `public static string class[int index]`.

Comment: I guess I'm confused I thought 'The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class. Static member functions do not have a this pointer.'  was explaining that since there is no object for the this pointer to reference, you couldn't use the reference to it.  And I also stated msdn was the one who uses that definition.  public static string vs. public string will never overlap as to my knowledge due to the fact one access the generic type object, while the other will access an instance object.

Answer (score -5):

The reason is because it is quite hard to understand what exactly you are indexing with a static indexer.

You say that the code would benefit from a static indexer, but would it really? All it would do is change this:

```
ConfigurationManager.editProperty(name, value);
...
value = ConfigurationManager.getProperty(name)
```

Into this:

```
ConfigurationManager[name] = value
...
value = ConfigurationManager[name]
```

which does not make the code better in any way; it is not smaller by many lines of code, it isn't easier to write thanks to autocomplete and it is less clear, as it hides the fact that you are getting and setting something you call 'Property' and it actually forces the reader to go read the documentation on what exactly the indexer returns or sets, because it is in no way obvious that it is a property that you are indexing for, while with both:

```
ConfigurationManager.editProperty(name, value);
...
value = ConfigurationManager.getProperty(name)
```

You can read it out loud and immediately understand what the code does.

Remember that we want to write code that is easy (= fast) to understand, not code that is fast to write. Do not mistake the speed at which you can lay down the code with the speed at which you complete projects.

Comment: Disagree. That's merely a conceptual point. And the code does look better in my opinion, although that is merely my opinion.

Comment: The need/want to create a static indexer isn't necessarily to create "faster to write" code, as at least in my current case, it really wouldn't, In my case since I am essentially creating a static 2D map, and all of the relevant properties (ie width and height) already exist, it would make sense that my map would also have an indexer (I could provide direct access to the map, but setting the values of the map is done internally)