# How to write a class that (like array) can be indexed with `arr[key]`?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, indexer

Like we do `Session.Add("LoginUserId", 123);`
and then we can access `Session["LoginUserId"]`, like an Array, how do we implement it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx):

```
public Thing this[string index]
{
    get
    {
         // get the item for that index.
         return YourGetItemMethod(index)
    }
    set
    {
        // set the item for this index. value will be of type Thing.
        YourAddItemMethod(index, value)
    }
}
```

This will let you use your class objects like an array:

```
MyClass cl = new MyClass();
cl["hello"] = anotherObject;
// etc.
```

There's also a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) available if you need more help.

**Addendum**:

You mention that you wanted this to be available on a static class. That get's a little more complicated, because you can't use a static indexer. If you want to use an indexer, you'd need to access it off of a static Field or some such sorcery as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401232/static-indexers/401275#401275).

Comment: why not inherit from Dictionary<string, T> ?

Comment: I gave the most basic way to do what he wanted. I don't know how he stores the collected objects, so he can use anything he likes from within an Indexer. Inheriting from Dictionary will just make what amounts to an alias for a Dictionary of predetermined types unless he overrides the right methods.

Comment: @Jake Basile, How do I write Add method? and unlike Indexers, I wouldn't like to  create its object and using it like static class.

Comment: @eFriend, what do you need to do that you can't do with a normal Dictionary?

Comment: Normal dictionary is your solution (it has Add, Remove, etc. and also indexer[string]), if you need specific actions for your class, create a class and inherit it from Dictionary<string, object>. Sometimes I see strange things in SO, I proposed this answer and I got -3 !!!

Comment: @valipour, I agree with you. Sometimes it's better not to give the original poster of the question exactly what they **think** they want! just like the customers ;) But I believe your answer was downvoted because you just pasted code with no context.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like all you need is a [generic dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

```
var session = new Dictionary<string, object>();

//set value
session.Add("key", value);

//get value
var value = session["key"] as string;
```

If you want to make this *static*, just make it a static member in another class.

```
public static class SharedStorage
{
   private static Dictionary<string, object> _data = new Dictionary<string,object>();
   public static Dictionary<string, object> Data { get { return _data; } }
}
```

Then you can access it as such, without having to initialize it:

```
SharedStorage.Data.Add("someKey", "someValue");
string someValue = (string) SharedStorage.Data["someKey"];
```

If you want to be more adventurous and are using .NET 4 you can also use an [Expando Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx), like the ViewBag member available to controllers in ASP.NET MVC 3:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.UserId = 5;
var userId = (int) expando.UserId;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use indexers
See the link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With the way you usually use the Session variable all you really need is a [generic Dictionary collection like this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). You don't really need to write a class. But if you need to add extra functionality and/or semantics you could certainly wrap the collection with a class and just include and indexer.

For other collections check out the [Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sbxh9x2%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) namespace.

Comment: I want a simple class like Session. I should be able to 
a) Use without creating object, like static
b) Using Add method to add elements
c) accessing like array

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Session in this case *is* an object, though.

Comment: @eFriend, take a look at my answer to see how you would do this in a static way.