# Creating static [] operator

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create static class with [] Operator?

On non static classes the syntax is pretty simple:

```
   public V this[K key]
        {
            get
            {
               //get stuff...
            }
            set
            {
               //set stuff....
            }
        }
```

However, I can't find a way to this on static objects.

Comment: [Static Indexers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401232/static-indexers)

Comment: yes, put it (the link) as answer so I can mark it

Comment: link-only answers are bad. you can get downvotes from it `:D`

Comment: nm, I flagged it as duplicate - not sure if I'll get points for cleaning up or loose points for duplicate questions ;)