# C# Class array?

Tags: c#

The following seems to be a class array?

```
Chemical.ChemicalName[IndexNumber]
```

It seems  that there are several other fields associated with Chemical, such as Cost, Quantity, `SupplierName` (Chemical.Cost etc).

I was wondering what this type of variable is called? A class array? I've been searching online about arrays and can't seem to find any documentation on this.

And secondly, how do I declare such a variable?

Comment: It's just a property of a type that implements an indexer.

Comment: its just a class that has an [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) on it.

Comment: Instead of essentially asking "what type of code can syntactically correct for `Chemical.ChemicalName[IndexNumber]` expression" you could have shown actual definition instead... Now people will list you all options - field vs. property, array/list/dictionary/string/custom indexer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable would look something like that

```
public class Chemical{
 public ChemicalName[] ChemicalNames = new ChemicalName[5];

  ...
}
```

So you can invoke it like that

```
Chemical c = new Chemical();
c.ChemicalNames[index];
```

OR, you can also declare the Array as static so you wont need an intance of the class to get the array e.g.

```
public class Chemical{
 public static ChemicalName[] ChemicalNames = new ChemicalName[5];

  ...
}
```

to call a static, simply use class.variable/method name

```
Chemical.ChemicalNames[index];
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's a property, not an array , so you cannot access using an index,

```
public class Chemical
{
    // Field
    public string ChemicalName;
    ...etc
}
```

if chemical is an array , then you can declare like this,

```
Chemical[] Chemicals = new Chemical[200];
```

Then you can access the particular element using the index,

```
Chemicals[IndexNumber].ChemicalName
```

**EDIT**

If you want to have ChemicalName as a array inside the class,

```
public class Chemical{
 public ChemicalName[] ChemicalNames = new ChemicalName[5];
]
```

you can access like this,

```
Chemical[] Chemicals = new Chemical[200];
c[index].ChemicalNames[index];
```

Comment: in question it says, `Chemical.ChemicalName[IndexNumber]` but your answer is  `Chemicals[IndexNumber].ChemicalName` both are different. you are using array of object of the class op may look for an array of properties of the class.

Comment: @un-lucky OP's question was not clear, anyway modified the answer

Comment: why do people upvote and downvote? mention the reason

Comment: I didn't downvote but your opening statement `It is a property, not an array` doesn't make sense - it can be both a property *and* an array, they're not mutually exclusive. Your example with `ChemicalName` *would infact* work, because the indexer will be selecting the nth character in the string, as well.

Comment: @Rob Op has not mentioned anything. its based on the assumption. anyway it has answers for both

Comment: @Sajeetharan : there is no downvote, Somebody removed the upvote after cast. now its retained.

Comment: @Sajeetharan You missed my point with your edit `Assuming it's a property, not an array` :) - Just because something is a property, doesn't mean its type cannot be an array. And your first example still incorrectly says you cannot use an indexer, because you *can* use an indexer on a string.

Answer (score 2):

It is a class property that implements [an indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx). Usually this is an array, but it can be something else as long as it implements `this[int index]`.

You can declare one by declaring it as a class property. For example,

```
class Book
{
    public Book(int numPages)
    {
        Pages = new Page[numPages];
    }
    public Page[] Pages {get;}
}
```

You can then instantiate an instance and access a page.

```
Book myBook = new Book(100);
myBook.Pages[50]=new Page("Hi, welcome to Page 50");
Console.Write(myBook.Pages[50].GetText());
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me consider this statement from the question `Chemical.ChemicalName[IndexNumber]`, We can consider `Chemical` as a class or as an object of some other class. If it is a class means the `ChemicalName` will be a static.

Then comes the `ChemicalName` definitely it will be a collection(List/Array or something like that) or even an object of a class which having an [`indexer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

*Case 1*: **consider `Chemical` is class and `ChemicalName` is a List of string** So the Definition will be :

```
public class Chemical
{
   public static List<string> ChemicalNames = new List<string>(){"name1","name 2"};
}
```

So that you can access a single name like the following:

```
string someChemicalName=Chemical.ChemicalNames[0]; // will be name1
```

*Case 2*: **consider `Chemical` is an object of a class and `ChemicalName` is a List of string** So the Definition will be :

```
public class Chemicals
{
   public List<string> ChemicalNames;
}
```

Then you can access create the `Chemical` by using the following code:

```
Chemicals Chemical= new Chemicals();
Chemical.ChemicalNames=new List<string>(){"name1","name 2"};
```

Here also you can workout your statement like this

```
string someChemicalName=Chemical.ChemicalNames[0]; // will be name1
```

Comment: You've missed the case when `Chemical` is variable name and the explanation that `Chemical.ChemicalName` can't be static class name, but those are non practical cases.

Answer (score 1):

Let's parse `Chemical.ChemicalName[IndexNumber]`:

`IndexNumber` is probably some value of one of integer types - let guess `int IndexNumber`. Other options could be enum or any type as you can use indexer with any arguments.

`[IndexNumber]` is indexing something. Since there is no 
[Static Indexers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401232/static-indexers) in C# it means `ChemicalName` can't be class name of static class like following

```
 namespace Chemical { 
    static class ChemicalName{}
 }
```

so it means that `ChemicalName` is either property or field of `Chemical`.

Now for `Chemical` there are more options

- it could be static class with `ChemicalName` as static property:

  ```
  static class Chemical{
     public static string[] ChemicalName = new[] {"Food", "Poison"};
  }
  ```
- it could be local variable of some type that has `ChemicalName` as instance property:

  ```
  class ChemicalType{
     public string[] ChemicalName = new[] {"Food", "Poison"};
  }

  ...
  void MyMethod()
  {
     // implicitly typed, same as `ChemicalType Chemical`
     var Chemical = new ChemicalType();
     int IndexNumber = 1;

     Console.WriteLine(Chemical.ChemicalName[IndexNumber]);
  }
  ```
- it could be field or property of your class (with any accessibility as to get `Checmical.ChemicalName` syntax to work for property it need to be used inside a method of your class)

  ```
  class MyClass
  {
     // one of any combination:
     // private field
     ChemicalType Chemical = new ChemicalType();

     // or protected automatic property
     protected ChemicalType Chemical {get;set;}

     // or public property
     ChemicalType  _chemical;
     public ChemicalType Chemical {get {return _chemical;}}
     ...
  }
  ```

Finally let's see what `ChemicalName` could be: the only requirement is to allow [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) by some type. including int. This gives very broad set of types as many of built in types support indexing.

- array is most common one `string[] ChemicalName`
- just string - somewhat strange given name of variable, but possible - `string ChemicalName`. When indexing will give single char result
- `List<string>`
- dictionary, this option allows broader range of indexing - i.e. by strings `Dictionary<string,string> ChemicalName`.
- custom type implementing similar to `public string this[int i]` (or any other return type).