# C# the name 'Cache' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, winforms, caching

I'm trying to store some values in the `Cache` to use them later and I think that this is what I need https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61.aspx, but can't get it to work...

This is how I try to use it (added `using System.Web`) :

```
Cache["name"] = "my name";
```

And it says:

> The name 'Cache' does not exist in the current context

What am I missing?

Comment: `using System.Web.Caching`

Comment: This returns: `The type or namespace name 'Caching' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Cache Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The instance of `Cache` that is accessed by the snippet below is a member of the `Page` object that this sample inherits.

Your code must be in a `Page` method. You have also another instance available on the `HttpContext`, again, described on the same link:

> One instance of this class is created per application domain, and it remains valid as long as the application domain remains active. Information about an instance of this class is available through the `Cache` property of the `HttpContext` object or the `Cache` property of the `Page` object.

You have to consider that `Cache["<somestring>"]` it *must* be an instance, not the class, since a class [cannot have a *static* index accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401232/static-indexers). So any sample you see like that, it *must* be a an instance, likely a property named `Cache` of some object.

Comment: This means that I can't use the `Cache` method in a `Windows Forms` Application?

Comment: You can *instantiate* a `Cache`  and use it. But, in a forms application, it begs the question *why*? A web page back end has to deal with HTTP request lifecycle, but a forms app it does not. An app can simply use a variable to 'cache' something.

Comment: My scope is to store a variable and display it in an input field when the user opens the form

Comment: For Winforms apps there is [`System.Runtime.Caching`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace you can use, with classes like `MemoryCache`, `ObjectCache`, `SqlChangeMonitor `, `FileChangeMonitor` and so on.

Comment: Tried that too, but I still get the error `The type or namespace name 'Caching' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You want to persist something between application restart? Then use a [User scoped Setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) and save it.

Comment: "The output caching functionality and types in the System.Runtime.Caching namespace were introduced in .NET Framework 4."

Comment: I think that the `User scope Setting` is what I need to use. Thank you!