# pass parameter to C# method with [Square brackets]

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

how to pass parameter between [Name]
please see

```
 public static string GetNationalCode(string Name)
 {
            foreach(var User in Users)
            {
                if(User.Name== Name)
                {
                    return User.Code;
                }
            }
            return "";
  }
```

I want to convert the top method to this code

```
  public static string GetNationalCode[string Name]()
  {
            foreach(var User in Users)
            {
                if(User.Name== Name)
                {
                    return User.Code;
                }
            }
            return "";
 }
```

Comment: You can't. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: What is the value in making this change?  What goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: GetNationalCode(List<string> nameList) i assume, and then foreach(var name in nameList) { ... } ? At Least i think that is your question but i am not sure. (your locals should not start with capitals by the way) | and where do you get Users from is that a this.Users ?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers

Comment: What you're describing, an indexed *non-default* property, is possible in VB.NET but not in C#. In C#, it's emulated by returning an object that has an indexer  (indexed *default* property), as germi's answer says. You could write it in VB.NET, although it doesn't use square brackets, and then in C#, you'd be calling `get_GetNationalCode(name)` (although you'd probably remove `Get` so it ends up being `get_NationalCode(name)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for are [Indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/).

As @Rotem points out in the comments though, indexers are not possible as static methods (as [discussed here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/401275/1344058)).

Comment: What led you to that conclusion and how do indexers tie into a static method?

Comment: @Rotem I'm guessing OP is misunderstanding what square brackets are generally used for, so this would probably be the place to start.

Comment: @Rotem They don't. It just seemed to me that that's what the OP was looking for. That they are not possible as static is a good point that I should mention in the answer, though.